# Brain freeze when applying mocking concepts to real-life unit test

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

I am quite new to concepts related to unit test and mocks. Please excuse my ignorance if its a dumb question or the example I came up with to understand the concepts. Let's say I have following interface

```
public interface IMyService
{
    OrderConfirmation ProcessOrder(Order order);
}
```

The Order and OrderConfirmation classes are defined as follows.

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}

public class OrderConfirmation
{
    public int OrderConfirmationId { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public Shipment ShipmentDetails { get; set; }
}

public class Shipment
{
    public int ShipmentId { get; set; }
    public DateTime ShipmentDate { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set; }
}
```

The implementation of class implementing IMyService interface is as follows. The key here is that it has a dependency on a data provider which is injected via constructor.

```
public class MyService : IMyService

{
    private IDataProvider DataProvider;

    public MyService(IDataProvider dataProvider)
    {
        DataProvider = dataProvider;
    }

    public OrderConfirmation ProcessOrder(Order request)
    {
        // bunch of operations here including calling various methods of DataProvider to save/retrieve data from databse.

    }
}
```

The IDataProvider interface has bunch of operations to store/retrieve data from database.

```
public interface IDataProvider

{
    List<Product> GetAllProducts();
    int CreateOrder(int customerId, List<Product> products);
    int CreateOrderConfirmation(int OrderConfirmationId, int orderId);
    void UpdateListOfAvailableProducts(List<Product> products);

}
```

In order to test the ProcessOrder method, it seems that I will have to somehow mock all the methods of IDataProvider interface but I have really confused about how to provide mocked implementation (using) moq. Can someone please show me any examples on how to accomplish this?

Comment: https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart

Comment: Show the method under test, how IDataProvider interface is exercised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one of many hypothetical examples how the mock of the data provider dependency could look like. *But notice that it is very vague to say something without seeing the real implementation of the tested method*. HTH

```
[TestMethod]
public void ProcessOrder_WhenSomeTestedCondition_ThenCertainExpectedResult()
{
    // Arrange
    OrderConfirmation expectedResult = new OrderConfirmation(); // Set expected result here
    Order fakeRequest = new Order();
    List<Product> fakeProducts = new List<Product>();
    int fakeCreateOrderResult = 123;
    int fakeCreateOrderConfirmationResult = 456;

    // This is the mocked dependency
    Mock<IDataProvider> dataProviderMock = new Mock<IDataProvider>();

    // Here the method is setup so it returns some fake products
    dataProviderMock.Setup(dp => dp.GetAllProducts())
        .Returns(fakeProducts);

    // Here the method is setup so it returns some fake result
    dataProviderMock.Setup(dp => dp.CreateOrder(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<List<Product>>()))
        .Returns(fakeCreateOrderResult);

    // Here the method is setup so it returns some fake result
    dataProviderMock.Setup(dp => dp.CreateOrderConfirmation(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>()))
        .Returns(fakeCreateOrderConfirmationResult);

    // Here the method UpdateListOfAvailableProducts returns void so
    // an example using callback is shouwing how the provided list of new products
    // could update the existing ones
    dataProviderMock.Setup(dp => dp.UpdateListOfAvailableProducts(
        new List<Product> { new Product {Price = 100, ProductId = 1, ProductName = "Product_X"}}))
        .Callback<List<Product>>(np =>
        {
            fakeProducts.AddRange(np);
        });

    // This is class under test which receives the mocked data provider object
    MyService service = new MyService(dataProviderMock.Object);

    // Act
    // Here the tested method is executed
    OrderConfirmation actualResult = service.ProcessOrder(fakeRequest);

    // Assert
    // Compare expected and actual results
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult.OrderId, actualResult.OrderId);
}
```